# Drawing: centering objects of different size

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

This program draws two circles of the inputted size on a jPanel, one on top of another. The problem is, the two circles are not centered. How can i solve this?

Code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

jPanel.Repaint();
try{
    jLabel6.setText("");
    int a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()); 

    Graphics2D gfx=(Graphics2D)jPanel1.getGraphics();
    gfx.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); 

    gfx.setColor(Color.red);
    gfx.fillOval(100,50,a,a);
    gfx.fillOval(100,50,a,a);

}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    jLabel6.setText("Incorrect data");
}
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This involves just a little geometry and algebra. I suspect that with just a little more effort you can figure this out. I have supreme faith in you. Just try. Work it out on paper first.

Comment: I guess i skipped math that day, but maybe ill manage :)

Comment: Also, you're doing your graphics all wrong: don't call `getGraphics()` on a component to get a Graphics object since the object thus obtained will not persist. To prove that this is true, minimize and then restore a rendered GUI, and you'll see your drawing disappear. Instead do your drawing in the `paintComponent` override of a JPanel or JComponent.

Comment: Forgive me my java freshness (My hovercraft is full of eels!).

Comment: No need to ask for forgiveness. Instead fix.

Comment: I solved the problem-partially: `gfx.fillOval(400-(a/2),50-(a/2),a,a);`. Partially, because it displaces the drawn circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is, the two circles are not centered.

You have to understand that how x, y coordinate works in Swing custom drawing to position the component.

Try to understand the below screenshot.

[image]

---

Add `width / 2` in the original `x` to get the centered `x` coordinate based on oval's width.

Do the same for height as well.

Sample code:

```
    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int size = 100;

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);

    int center = x + size / 2;
    size = 70;
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(center - size / 2, center - size / 2, size, size);
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work (tried), but nice explanation with Java mascots.

Comment: I have modified my post. you have to first calculate the center of first red circle then draw the next blue circle based on center coordinate.

Comment: First draw circle of bigger size otherwise it will be hidden by blue circle.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I used: `gfx.fillOval(400-(a/2),50-(a/2),a,a);`, and adjusted the x,y coordinates, to generate the circles on the desired position.